# Optimization of a MATCH statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (t1:Tel {TB:true})<-[:TelBIZ]-
  (:ACC {TB:true})-[or:REBIZ {movOre:t1.nuTel}]->
  (:ACC {TB:true})-[:TelBIZ]->(t2:Tel {TB:true,nuTel:or.movBene}) 
WHERE t1.nuTel<>t2.nuTel
RETURN t1, t2, COUNT(or) AS Ope, SUM(or.imp) AS Total, 
  10^3 as Precision, max(or.Txt) AS mRB
```

I am trying to get this query to return few values, but I find the query is not optimised and returns a lot of data. Please suggest me how I can optimize it. I am using Neo4j v3.5.

Comment: Is your only question that you are getting more results than you expect? If so, can you describe what you expected versus what you got?

Comment: I am getting values but the query is taking to long to run.

Comment: I was trying to optimise the code but didn't worked as expected.

Comment: Does the query posted here return correct results, but takes a very long time?

Comment: Yes exactly.it return results but it's too slow

Comment: Without a profile of the query execution (`PROFILE <your query>`), it's hard to suggest much. An index on a property like `TB` with two values might be useless (depending on the distribution). An index on the `nuTel` property of nodes with label `Tel` might help: `CREATE INDEX ON :Tel(nuTel)`. Otherwise post the results of `PROFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is that you have a long pattern, and within that pattern you have a condition that uses a property of a node in that pattern.

That is, you match on t1 and require `{movOre: t1.nutel}`, and the same thing again when you use a REBIX relationship property to filter on `t2: Tel`

This means every t1 has to be found, and every value of `t1.nuTel` used in the pattern. If you have 1000 Tel nodes, you have 1000 nuTel properties. Basically, the possibilities for nuTel and movBene are exploding.

You might refactor to split this into multiple MATCH statements:

```
MATCH (t1:Tel {TB:true})
WITH distinct t1.nuTel as t1nuTel
MATCH (t1:Tel {TB:true, nulTel:t1nuTel})<-[:TelBIZ]-(:ACC {TB:true})-[or:REBIZ {movOre: t1nuTel}]->(:ACC {TB:true})->(t2:Tel {TB:true, nuTel: or.movBene})
WHERE t1.nuTel <> t2.nuTel
RETURN t1, t2, count(or) as Ope, sum(or.imp) as Total, 10^3 as Precision, max(or.Txt) as mRB
```

That may not be the best solution for your graph, and there's still the issue with `or.movBene` being used as a filter when it's part of a pattern, but hopefully I've communicated the idea and you can refine from there.

Also, indexes on nuTel, movBene, and TB will be incredibly faster, if you don't haver them already.